# Using jenkins wanted to copy some script file to /bin/

Tags: shell, jenkins, sudo

Using jenkins I have created one job and I have script files in git and i wanted to copy in /bin/. I have tried using sudo. I have tried to copy from jenkins workspace to bin but unable to copy

```
echo 'password'|sudo cp -S /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/WiCheck_project/sample.sh /bin/
```

but it it giving following error.

```
[sudo] password for jenkins: Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for jenkins: 
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Please help me how to use sudo to copy files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's asking for your password to run `sudo`. you could use `expect` to inject it if you hate yourself.

or, if you have access to the slave, you could read about sudoers and update the sudoers file or add a file to sudoers.d to allow the jenkins user to run `sudo cp` passwordless.

or you could `chown` the `/bin` directory to the jenkins user so you don't have to use `sudo`.

or, the best option, just use `./WiCHeck_project/sample.sh` to run your script instead of `sample.sh`, so it won't have to be in `/bin`.